# Why is my clipboard data gone after closing the form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, clipboard

I'm trying to copy text from a RichtTextBox to the clipboard. The problem is that after closing the form that contains this text, the data on the clipboard is gone. <strike>I have tried the following in code:</strike>

I tried different ways to copy something already (seperately):

```
Dim data As String = RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf

Clipboard.SetText(data, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, data)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, True)
RichTextBox1.Copy()
```

With and without specifying RTF, the result stays the same. Also with a normal string of text and/or when using shortcut CTRL+C. And also when passing 'True' as parameter to SetDataObject or not, nothing changes.

I opened a WordPad window to test this out; copy and paste when the dialog is still open results in a normal paste. Closing the dialog (but not the application) clears the clipboard and pasting again results in nothing or a new line.

Anyone who knows why this behavior occurs and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be when close any dispose statement

Comment: I have no handler attached to any event that occurs when closing the form.

Comment: You're clearing the Clipboard when that Form closes or in the Form that opened it, if it's modal. If you added a Clipboard hook using the Clipboard Viewers Chain model, use `AddClipboardFormatListener` instead.

Comment: If I remember right, this goes back to VB6!

Comment: All of these clipboard commands will override each other. Each will replace the content of the clipboard completely.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, each of these clipboard calls you make completely replaces the clipboard content, so executing them all in a row doesn't work; only the last one will actually have any effect.

As for your issue, the problem is that `Clipboard.SetDataObject` can indeed be used with any object, but then it figures out the type automagically, so it will probably just see it's a `String` and put it in as type `Text`, not `RTF`. The *intended* way to use it, though, which is [woefully underdocumented in the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setdataobject?view=netframework-4.8), is with an object of the `DataObject` class. I'm not sure why they didn't make specific `SetDataObject(DataObject, ...)` overloads for that; it would make things so much more clear to the users. Seems like pure laziness to me that they didn't, to be honest.

So, anyway, to use the `Clipboard.SetDataObject(?, True)` overload, which ensures that data persists after the application closes, *and* make it set your content type correctly, you need to make the first argument an object of that `DataObject` class. So first make a `New DataObject`, then put the string into using `SetData`, which allows explicitly specifying the type, and finally call the `SetDataObject` function with your `DataObject`, and the argument to retain the data on the clipboard.

```
' Get rich text snippet
Dim data As String = RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf
' Create data object
Dim dataObj As New DataObject()
' Put rich text snippet in data object
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, data)
' Put data object in clipboard, using the "copy=True" argument.
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, True)
```

Note that `DataObject` is a *collection* of clipboard data, meant to be used to put things on the clipboard in multiple types *simultaneously*. For example, you could add the snippet both as RTF and as plain text, ensuring that your copied content can also be pasted in applications like Notepad:

```
Dim dataObj As New DataObject()
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Text, RichTextBox1.SelectedText)
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, True)
```

Comment: I've edited my original question to be more clear. I just wanted to show I've already tried multiple different things to get this to work. I did not run all the functions at once. But thanks for clarifying and answering. I'll give your suggestion a try as soon as possible!

Comment: After testing this out, we got a little but further but still didn't get the desired result. The text stays in the clipboard, even after the form closes. This is one step in the right direction. However, when closing the whole program, the text still gets cleared.

Comment: I've tested this, and, even without this special code, the normal Ctrl+C of a RichTextBox control copies the text just fine, and remembers it after the application closes. Are you sure there isn't any _other_ code in the program that may affect or clear the clipboard?